# \ead not producing email address in elsarticle class

Tags: elsarticle

I am wondering very simply if there is a solution in the document class `elsarticle` to `\ead` not producing the corresponding author's email address. I have attached my code below:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{This is my title}
\author[label1]{John Smith\corref{cor1}}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\address[label1]{Department of Mathematics, Arbitrary State University, City, AB 00000, United States}
\date{August 2022}




\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    This is my sample abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `label1` should be `cor1`?

Comment: See here the examples on how to make the title page. http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf

Comment: There is no `\ead` command in the example.